# Linking to a kernel module a precompiled object file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i'd need to link to my linux kernel module a precompiled object file. if i have a row in the makefile like this:

```
obj-m := test.o
test-objs := obj1.o obj2.o
```

where for obj1.o exists a obj1.c source file while obj2.o is a precompiled object file obj1 are correctly builded but make tries to build also obj2.o by searching an obj2.c source file. How can i specify that obj2.o is a precompiled object?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply rename the shipped `.o` file to `.o_shipped`. In your case :

- leave your Makefile as is
- `mv obj2.o obj2.o_shipped`
- make and let the kernel build system magic do the work for you :)