# How to add prebuilt object when building linux driver (android)

Tags: makefile, driver

It's required that the source file of my driver won't be opened for now, so what's the best way to do it ?

currently, I have a idea that is that possible to put the prebuilt object files (.o) and let the makefile compile them as the final built-in.o, but I don't know how to write the Makefile to handle this thing.

Any help is very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by [Linking to a kernel module a precompiled object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507631/linking-to-a-kernel-module-a-precompiled-object-file)

> Simply rename the shipped .o file to .o_shipped. In your case :
>
> - leave your Makefile as is
> - mv obj2.o obj2.o_shipped
> - make and let the kernel build system magic do the work for you :)